# How to make "salt-crust-baked" chicken?

Tags: chicken, salt

A while back I heard mention of a way to bake/roast chicken that supposedly would make it very good and juicy.  Unfortunately I didn't get the details, so I haven't dared try it myself.  I was wondering if someone here had done this or something similar, and could describe the methode (especially temperature and timing) to me - and confirm that this actually work and give a good result.

The idea was to take a whole (or half would do?) chicken (I assumed plucked, cleaned and ready for cooking), and cover it with salt!  You would basically take *lots* of salt and add a little water, so you got a thick "goo" of salt.  Then you would cover the chicken with this salt-goo in a thick layer.  Then you would put the salt-goo covered chicken in the oven to bake.  In the oven, the salt-goo would become a thick salt-crust, that would trap in the moisture.  When finished, you just crack the salt-crust open.

Does this actually work?!  I can't help but thinking that the result would be a *very salty* chicken...

Comment: why would the result be a very salty chicken? You don't eat the salt, it's there to provide insulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work? Yes, it does.

The idea is to create something akin to an individual "dutch oven" around the chicken or fish you are baking. The meat is "steamed" in his own juices. There are a bunch of different "recipes" for the salt crust, often with some "binding agent" like egg whites.
Usually, the skin is removed when serving (go ahead, give it a try, if you like), so rest assured that the meat underneath is not too salty.

An alternative to salt (and arguably more "paleo style") would be baking in clay.

A quick internet search should yield plenty of recipes for both varieties. 
(Remenber: asking for recipes is a big no-no here.)